# Predicate doesn't work "the other way"

Tags: prolog, dcg

This function takes a string and makes it to pirate language.

But it doesn't work when I want it to take pirate language and return the normal language.

```
  :- dynamic (lang/2).
  lang([],[]).
  lang(Text, Text2) :-
    [Head|Tail] = Text,
    lang(Tail,X2),
    (member(Head,[101,97,105,111,117,121])
        -> append([Head],X2,Text2)
        ; append([Head,111,Head],X2,Text2)
        ).
```

it works when calling `lang([list of hex codes for chars], X).`
But it doesn't work with `lang(X, [answer from above])`.

Comment: You don't need `dynamic(lang/2)` unless you plan to dynamically assert or retract facts of the form `lang/2`.

Comment: Note that `append([Head], X2, Test2)` is equivalent to, `[Head|X2] = Test2`, and `append([Head,111,Head], X2, Test2)` equivalent to, `[Head,111,Head|X2] = Test2`, so you don't need `append/3` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a DCG, which is the right tool for this sort of processing, you can get both directions:

```
lang([]) --> [].
lang([H|T]) --> [H], { member(H, [101, 97, 105, 111, 117, 121]) }, lang(T).
lang([H,111,H|T]) --> [H], { \+ member(H, [101, 97, 105, 111, 117, 121]) }, lang(T).

lang(Text, Arg) :- phrase(lang(Arg), Text).
```

Query results:

```
| ?- lang("arg", L), atom_codes(A, L).

A = arorgog
L = [97,114,111,114,103,111,103] ? ;

no
| ?- lang(A, "arorgog"), atom_codes(L, A).

A = [97,114,103]
L = arg ? ;

no
| ?-
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to tidy it up. :)

Comment: Great solution! With `double_quotes` set to `codes`, you can write `[101,97,105,111,117,121]` as: `"eaiouy"`, which I find more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.
I split it up in two cases, one handling the case if the input is `([Head|Tail],[Head,111,Head])` and the other one when the input is `([Head|Tail],[Head|Rest])`.